# Energy of massless particles with the example of Magnon

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Consider this situation.

I am told that: at low temperatures magnons, the elementary excitations of a ferromagnetic ground state, can be treated as a gas of non-interacting, massless, spin-0 bosons with a dispersion relation $ω$ = $α$$k^2$ where $α$ is a constant.

Research online tells me that the energy should be $ћ$$ω$.  However, quantum mechanics tells me that momentum is equal to $ћ$$k$ and relativity then tells me that the energy is $E$=$p$$c$=$ћ$$k$$c$, which, considering the dispersion relation $ω$ = $α$$k^2$, gives a completely different expression for the energy.

Can someone please clear up this confusion?

Answer (score 0):

The relation $E = pc$ for massless particles comes from Lorentz invariance, specifically by requiring that the "length" of the 4-momentum, $E^2 - (pc)^2$ should be the same in all reference frames. Therefore, it only holds for *fundamental* particles, which magnons are not. Magnons do not occur in vacuum, they occur in solids, which spontaneously break Lorentz invariance since they have a preferred rest frame. Therefore magnons do not need to satisfy Lorentz invariance.